# using Jordan-Hahn decomposition to prove $|\int_{\Omega} f d\mu|\leq \int_{\Omega} |f| d|\mu|$

Tags: real-analysis

Let ($\Omega$, $F$) be a measurable space. Suppose $\mu$ is a finite signed measure on $F$ and $\mu=\mu^{+}-\mu^{-}$ is the Jordan-Hahn decomposition of $\mu$. Prove that if
$f :\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and Borel measurable, then

$$|\int_{\Omega} f d\mu|\leq \int_{\Omega} |f| d|\mu|$$

Comment: Do you know the definition of $|\mu|$? in terms of $\mu^+ $ and $\mu^-$

Comment: @Xiao $|\mu|=\mu^{+}+\mu^{-}$

Comment: Then can you show this inequality for any simple function $\chi_A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have (depending on your definition of $\int f \,d\mu$, this is either the definition or a simple consequence):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\big| \int f \, d\mu \big| = \big| \int f d\mu_+ - \int f d\mu_- \big|.
\end{eqnarray*}

How does that help you?

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple:

$\big| \int_\Omega f d\mu \big| = \big| \int_\Omega f d\mu^+ - \int_\Omega d\mu^- \big| \leq \int_\Omega |f| d\mu^+ + \int_\Omega |f| d\mu^- = \int_\Omega |f| d(\mu^+ + \mu^- ) = \int_\Omega |f| d|\mu| $